# Quickly labeling some elements according to the most occuring labels

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

Suppose I have vector of components (each component is a vector of floats)

```
vector<vector<float> > components
```

and I have a vector of data (each data is a vector of floats of same size as component)

```
vector< vector<float> > data
```

and the labels associated this data

```
vector<string> labels
```

(here I mean `label[i]` is the label of `data[i]`). I also have a distance function that return the distance between two vectors

```
float distance(vector<float> v1, vector<float> v2);
```

I want to give a label to each components according to the most occurring label among data associated to this component; i.e. something as following:

```
for each data d from data
{
   let c the nearest component from d according to distance.
   associate the label of d to c.
}

for each component c
{
   definitely give to c the label that occur the most among labels associated to it
   // example if labels {l1,l2,l1,l2,l1,l1,l1,l8,l1} were associated to c, then its label should be l1
}
```

The final result that should be returned is a vector of labelled components (pairs of `<component,label>`) described as:

```
vector< pair< vector<float>, string > > labeledComponents.
```

What is the simple and quick way to do that in C++ ?

Answer (score 1):

This task is complex, and so there isn't a *super* simple and quick way in C++, but here's what I got:

```
typedef vector<float> componenttype;
typedef vector<float> datatype;
typedef map<string, int> possiblenames;
typedef vector<pair<componenttype, string>> resulttype;

float vecdistance(datatype v1, componenttype v2) {return 1.0;}

resulttype user995434(vector<datatype> data, vector<string> labels, vector<componenttype> components) {
    map<componenttype, possiblenames> maybenames;
    resulttype resultnames;

    //for each data d from data
    for(auto d=data.begin(); d!=data.end(); ++d) {
       //let c the nearest component from d according to distance.
       auto closest=components.begin();
       float closedistance = FLT_MAX;
       for(auto it=components.begin(); it!=components.end(); ++it) {
           float dist = vecdistance(*d, *it);
           if (dist < closedistance) {
               closedistance = dist; 
               closest = it;
           }
        }
        //associate the label of d to c.
        int offset = std::distance(data.begin(), d);
        maybenames[*closest][labels[offset]]++;
    }
    //for each component c
    for(auto c=components.begin(); c!=components.end(); ++c) {
        //let mostname be the name with the most matches.
        auto posnames = maybenames[*c];
        posnames[""]=0; //guarantee each component has _something_
        auto mostname = posnames.begin();
        for(auto it=posnames.begin(); it!=posnames.end(); ++it) {
            if (it->second > mostname->second)
                mostname = it;
        }
        //associate mostname with c
        resultnames.push_back(make_pair(*c, mostname->first));
    }
    return resultnames;
}
```

[Proof of compilation and execution here](http://ideone.com/8hlwI), though I have no validated it's accuracy in any way.

I should note that as you never mentioned any of the data being sorted in any way, nor any other things that could be used as shortcuts, this algorithm is not "quick", in any language.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have the algorithm for finding the label for C according to the data elements.  You will have to iterate through each element of `components` and see if the distance is less than the current minimum: if yes, remember the current component and set the min distance to the current distance.

*Note*: don't forget that more than one component can be to the same minimum distance, so keep a collection of the min-distance components, not just one

You can build a map (see `std::map<>`) of component to (map of label to occurrance number) then select the highest occurrance number for each component from this mapping

Comment: The problem is not the algorithm, I've already done it in python, but I want to transform and integrate it to an already existing C++ code (which is not coded by me). So I'm searching for a fast way to do it in C++, I'm not very familiar with this language.